# Region Growing python

Tags: python, opencv

I working on region growing algorithm implementation in python. But when I run this code on output I get black image with no errors. Use CV threshold function on input image and for seed value I use mouse click to store x,y values in tuple.

```
def get8n(x, y, shape):
    out = []
    if y-1 > 0 and x-1 > 0:
        out.append( (y-1, x-1) )
    if y-1 > 0 :
        out.append( (y-1, x))
    if y-1 > 0 and x+1 < shape[1]:
        out.append( (y-1, x+1))
    if x-1 > 0:
        out.append( (y, x-1))
    if x+1 < shape[1]:
        out.append( (y, x+1))
    if y+1 < shape[0] and x-1 > 0:
        out.append( ( y+1, x-1))
    if y+1 < shape[0] :
        out.append( (y+1, x))
    if y+1 < shape[0] and x+1 < shape[1]:
       out.append( (y+1, x+1))
    return out

def region_growing(img, seed):
    list = []
    outimg = np.zeros_like(img)

    list.append((seed[0], seed[1]))
    while(len(list)):
        pix = list[0]
        outimg[pix[0], pix[1]] = 255
        for coord in get8n(pix[0], pix[1], img.shape):
            if img[coord[0], coord[1]] > 0:
                outimg[coord[0], coord[1]] = 255
                list.append((coord[0], coord[1]))
        list.pop(0)
    return outimg

def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags, params): 
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: 
        print 'Seed: ' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y) 
        clicks.append((y,x)) 

clicks = []
image = cv2.imread('lena.jpg', 0) 
ret, img = cv2.threshold(image, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 
cv2.namedWindow('Input') 
cv2.setMouseCallback('Input', on_mouse, 0, ) 
cv2.imshow('Input', img) 
cv2.waitKey() 
seed = clicks[-1] 
cv2.imshow('Region Growing', region_growing(img, seed)) 
cv2.waitKey() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Since you are asking about reading and displaying an image, can you include the code where you read/manipulate the input image and display the output image?

Comment: There is all code for input image

`def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags, params):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print 'Seed: ' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y)
        clicks.append((y,x))

clicks = []
image = cv2.imread('lenna.jpg', 0)
ret, img = cv2.threshold(image, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.namedWindow('Input')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Input', on_mouse, 0, )
cv2.imshow('Input', img)
cv2.waitKey()
seed = clicks[-1]
cv2.imshow('Region Growing', region_growing(img, seed))
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

Comment: Add the code to the question, with proper formating - it's unreadable like this.

Comment: What do you expect your code to do? Right now it appears to draw a blank image with a white pixel in the last place you clicked. If you click in a white region of the input it goes into an infinite loop. On the other hand, it means that the output image is not black, but has a single white pixel.

Comment: I want to pass through all the neighbours pixels of seed pixel(clicked) and pixels whose value is greater than 0 set to 255. And continue that as long there are neighbour pixels greater than 0. And assign them to the region that will be the output image

Comment: Why is if "img[coord[0], coord[1]] > 0" included or what is its function? Or why cant the pixel be black?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had some trouble with your get8n() function so I rewrote it. I believe that the code below does what you were asking. There are two lines in the region_growing() function that are commented out. If you uncomment them they will show an animation of what is happening during the processing. It is a good way to visualize the code and give you a sense of where things are failing.

Also, in your code you left the possibility of adding pixels that you had already processed to your "to be processed" list. This was causing an infinite loop. I've added a check that prevents pixels that have already been processed from being added back into the list.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def get8n(x, y, shape):
    out = []
    maxx = shape[1]-1
    maxy = shape[0]-1
    
    #top left
    outx = min(max(x-1,0),maxx)
    outy = min(max(y-1,0),maxy)
    out.append((outx,outy))
    
    #top center
    outx = x
    outy = min(max(y-1,0),maxy)
    out.append((outx,outy))
    
    #top right
    outx = min(max(x+1,0),maxx)
    outy = min(max(y-1,0),maxy)
    out.append((outx,outy))
    
    #left
    outx = min(max(x-1,0),maxx)
    outy = y
    out.append((outx,outy))
    
    #right
    outx = min(max(x+1,0),maxx)
    outy = y
    out.append((outx,outy))
    
    #bottom left
    outx = min(max(x-1,0),maxx)
    outy = min(max(y+1,0),maxy)
    out.append((outx,outy))
    
    #bottom center
    outx = x
    outy = min(max(y+1,0),maxy)
    out.append((outx,outy))
    
    #bottom right
    outx = min(max(x+1,0),maxx)
    outy = min(max(y+1,0),maxy)
    out.append((outx,outy))
    
    return out

def region_growing(img, seed):
    seed_points = []
    outimg = np.zeros_like(img)
    seed_points.append((seed[0], seed[1]))
    processed = []
    while(len(seed_points) > 0):
        pix = seed_points[0]
        outimg[pix[0], pix[1]] = 255
        for coord in get8n(pix[0], pix[1], img.shape):
            if img[coord[0], coord[1]] != 0:
                outimg[coord[0], coord[1]] = 255
                if not coord in processed:
                    seed_points.append(coord)
                processed.append(coord)
        seed_points.pop(0)
        #cv2.imshow("progress",outimg)
        #cv2.waitKey(1)
    return outimg

def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags, params):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print 'Seed: ' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y), img[y,x]
        clicks.append((y,x))
        
clicks = []
image = cv2.imread('lena.bmp', 0)
ret, img = cv2.threshold(image, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.namedWindow('Input')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Input', on_mouse, 0, )
cv2.imshow('Input', img)
cv2.waitKey()
seed = clicks[-1]
out = region_growing(img, seed)
cv2.imshow('Region Growing', out)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the result when clicking on the left side of her hat:

[image: input and result]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I copied the code you wrote and I get the same result like above, with white pixel in place where I clicked. Can you show me your output result? Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Added a result image. If you are still having problems, I'd recommend printing the image value at your seed location to make sure you haven't got your x and y coordinates mixed up. These results are from the exact code that I posted.

Comment: Why is if "img[coord[0], coord[1]] != 0" included or what is its function? Or why cant the pixel be black?

Comment: The region_growing function runs on an image that has been thresholded, meaning the values are either 0 or 255. So the line could have been `if img[coord[0], coord[1]] == 255`. Or `if img[coord[0], coord[1]] > 0`. It is just checking if the pixel is black because that is the boundary condition in this case.

Comment: I think it's better not to overload the built-in `list` function for the list of the candidate seed points. I'll propose an edit

Comment: I think that there is another minor mistake: when passing `x, y` parameters to the `get8n` function inside `region_growing` `pix[0] and `pix[1]` should be inverted since `pix[1]` is the x coordinate and `pix[0]` is the y coordiunate, as `shape[1]-1` and `shape[0]-1` represent `maxx`and `maxy` respectively in the `get8n` function. I think that this will not cause errors until borders are reached.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions presented above are conceptually correct but from a numerical point of view they contain some strong problems making them order N^2 in the number of pixels. There is no need to search a pixel in a list if you can store the information in an array offering random access, also the connectedness function can be cythonized. Also it would be nice to be able to provide your own similarity function.

So here is my proposal for an improved, and definitely much faster version running in a Jupyter noteboook:

First cell for imports:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

%pylab inline 

%load_ext Cython
```

Second cell (don't merge which the first):

```
%%cython
# Use %%cython -a for more verbose output, note %%cython should be on the first line in the cell!
def get_8_connected(int x, int y, shape):
    cdef int xmax = shape[0]-1
    cdef int ymax = shape[1]-1
    cdef int connected_pixel_x 
    cdef int connected_pixel_y
    cdef int dx, dy
    
    connected_pixels = list()
    
    for dx in range(3):
        for dy in range(3):
            connected_pixel_x  = x + dx - 1
            connected_pixel_y = y + dy - 1
            if connected_pixel_x < 0 or connected_pixel_x > xmax or \
                connected_pixel_y < 0 or connected_pixel_y > ymax or \
                (connected_pixel_x == x and connected_pixel_y == y):
                    pass
            else: 
                connected_pixels.append((connected_pixel_x,connected_pixel_y)) 
    return  connected_pixels
```

Third cell with the region merging

```
def region_growing(img, 
                   seed_points, 
                   test = lambda seed_x, seed_y, x, y, img, outimg : img[x,y] != 0,
                   colormap=None):
    
    processed = np.full((img.shape[0],img.shape[1]), False)
    
    if colormap is None:
        outimg = np.zeros_like(img)
    else:
        outimg = np.zeros((img.shape[0],img.shape[1],colormap.shape[1]),dtype=np.uint8)
    
    for index, pix in enumerate(seed_points):
        processed[pix[0], pix[1]] = True
        if colormap is None:
            outimg[pix[0], pix[1]] = img[pix[0], pix[1]]
        else:
            outimg[pix[0], pix[1]]  = colormap[index % len(colormap)]
    
    while(len(seed_points) > 0):
        pix = seed_points[0]
            
        for coord in get_8_connected(pix[0], pix[1], img.shape):
            if not processed[coord[0],coord[1]]:
                test_result = test(pix[0], pix[1], coord[0], coord[1], img, outimg)
                if test_result:
                    outimg[coord[0], coord[1]]  = outimg[pix[0], pix[1]]
                    if not processed[coord[0],coord[1]]:
                        seed_points.append(coord)
                    processed[coord[0],coord[1]] = True
                    
        seed_points.pop(0)
    return outimg
```

and it can be called from another cell using the same logic as before:

```
def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags, params):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print( 'Seed: ' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y), img[y,x])
        clicks.append((int(y), int(x)))
        
clicks = []
image = cv2.imread('lena.bmp', 0)
ret, img = cv2.threshold(image, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.namedWindow('Input')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Input', on_mouse, 0, )
cv2.imshow('Input', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

seed = clicks
out = region_growing(img, seed)
cv2.imshow('Region Growing', out)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

There are some small functional difference. A region in the output is either marked by the value of the original image at the seed or by a value from the optional colormap. The colormap needs to specify RGB colors given als unsigned 8 bit integers. It is also possible to pass in a tailored test function, replacing:

```
test = lambda seed_x, seed_y, x, y, img, outimg : img[x,y] != 0
```

with for example:

```
test = lambda seed_x, seed_y, x, y, img, outimg : abs(img[x,y] - img[seed_x, seed_y]) < 4
```

would yield all pixels who are connected to the original seed with intensity steps below 4.

In my context it works for monochrome and color images. That is both for 2d arrays and 3D arrays.

If Cython cannot be used the function `get_8_connected` can be replaced by:

````
def get_8_connected(x, y, shape):
    xmax = shape[0]-1
    ymax = shape[1]-1
    
    connected_pixels = list()
    
    for dx in range(3):
        for dy in range(3):
            connected_pixel_x  = x + dx - 1
            connected_pixel_y = y + dy - 1
            if connected_pixel_x < 0 or connected_pixel_x > xmax or \
                connected_pixel_y < 0 or connected_pixel_y > ymax or \
                (connected_pixel_x == x and connected_pixel_y == y):
                    pass
            else:
                connected_pixels.append((connected_pixel_x,connected_pixel_y))
    return  connected_pixels```
````

Answer (score -4):

Add () for python 3.x like : print("Some things")